# Magento isn't upgradable through Magento Connect Manager

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, ce-1.9.1.0, magento-connect-manager

I have another store, where I can update Magento through Magento Connect. But this store is strange. **There aren't the package names to upgrade Magento.** Someone has a clue?

Magento Version 1.9.1.0

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind that is that **the Magento Connect Manager has not been initiated by a previous install/upgrade**. It could be because this store has been installed by transferring files via FTP.

Thus, the only method to upgrade you've got is by the CLI.

First, you need to ensure the permissions are right:

```
chmod 550 ./mage
```

Then you've got to initiate the mage:

```
./mage mage-setup .
```

And set your preferred state for the configuration:

```
./mage config-set preferred_state stable
```

Now, with a previously setup mage you could have run the following:

```
./mage list-installed
./mage list-upgrades
```

And then upgrade like this:

```
./mage upgrade-all
```

But in your case this won't list nor upgrade and you'll have to force the install of the upgrade by doing the following:

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

Once the upgrade is done, don't forget to reindex:

```
php shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

NB: after this upgrade, you'll be able to see the list of packages in the connect manager.