# Does magento connect manager not work on localhost?

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento-ce, magento-connect-manager

I'm about to upgrade my 1.9.2.2 Magento shop to 1.9.3, amongst others, for security reasons.

We have a workflow set up that enables us to test everything locally first, using vagrant. This is obviously encouraged.
However, using the manager it does not display that any plugins need updates. Running the same manager in my production environment, this DOES display which extensions (including the core) can be updated.

Is there some sort of restriction on using manager for localhost? Or better yet, is there some sort of config file, creating the login from the manager to Magento community, that may be misconfigured on my localhost?

I can't seem to upgrade my application, as patching it on production is just too ballsy (we have quite a few extensions).

I should note that I have only been working with Magento for a few months, and only learned about the manager today.

**UPDATE:**

It seems as if this case is related: [Magento isn't upgradable through Magento Connect Manager](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120549/magento-isnt-upgradable?rq=1)

I am not sure if that is still a thing though, as the server on which I am running the installation, was initiated through GIT, based on a production environment we had on a different server.
However, the manager IS working on production, so does not entirely explain. I will try on localhost.

Comment: replace download folder with new one or fresh Magento directories..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself!

While the issue does correctly share similarities with the aforementioned (and linked) issue elsewhere on stackexchange, the solution is different.

For anyone wondering, the problem was with an **oudated version of CURL on CentOS**.

I had to update curl and I am now able to run the CLI script to update magento. 
How to upgrade CURL is better explained in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495444/how-to-upgrade-php-curl-to-version-7-36-0