# ./mage No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, setup-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade Magento (from ver. 1.9.1.0) through the CLI using PuTTY.
I'm following this guide:

[Magento isn't upgradable through Magento Connect Manager](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120549/magento-isnt-upgradable-through-magento-connect-manager)

But it always give me same error whatever I write.
"No such file or directory"

What is the problem?

Thank you very much in advance for any suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the magento file in bin directory with the new one and run the following command on magento file if your host is linux:

**`sudo chmod u+x bin/magento`**
[image]

> Note: Before running bash command make sure your current working
>   directory must be Magento 2.x root.